# What are all the possible causes to the BackendError in Conversion API in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

The [Conversion API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/conversion/exceptions?hl=pl) reference says vaguely:

```
BackendError 
Error in backend that can't be sent back to application.
```

What are all the possible causes for this kind of error for HTML to PDF conversion?

The first item on the list would be:

1. Referencing a missing asset (like an image) in the HTML
2. …

Comment: Without providing details on what you're trying to do, this question isn't answerable.

Comment: I'm not looking for a solution to an error I got, rather I am looking for documentation supplement that clearly states what type of operations that can case this error. I understand that this question may have a answer with a very very long list of causes but listing the most prominent can help debugging. On the other hand there can be just a handful of situations that a this error is raised and then naming those situations should definitely help a lot. The first would be: Referencing a missing asset.